# What does the ∴ character do in a bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell

Stumbled across the ∴ operator in some of the rvm install scripts and couldn't seem to locate information on what it does? Is there documentation on this somewhere?

Comment: Is that really a character used in shell scripts? I've never seen that character used in any script - maybe I just haven't noticed it.

Comment: I think it is called the "Therefore" symbol, but I don't think it is a valid scripting character.  Perhaps it was used in a comment, or to conclude a series of steps for informational purposes (not functional purposes)

Comment: What the hell, this must be from the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll guarantee it's not a `bash` thing. UNIX is famous for the terseness of its commands but even it wouldn't go that far :-)

It's possible that RVM may create a script or executable with that name so that entering it on the command line may do something but, if that's so, it's a good reason for me to avoid RVM.

However, since the [context](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) seems to be lines like:

```
∴ bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )
∴ rvm update
∴ gem update rvm && rvm-install
```

I would suggest it's the prompt in use for the shell rather than a command.

Answer (score 0):

It does nothing - that seems to be the character that wayneseguin is using for his bash prompt. Many might see `:~` instead by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Unicode 0x2234 character meaning "therefore". This is definitely not a bash operator.

I guess you found this character on http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ and thought it would belong to the command line. Maybe they just use it on the website to indicate a shell (usually indicated by # or $).

Answer (score 0):

```
cat <<∴
Very unlikely to find an accidental ∴
at the beginning of a line in a here
document. But it would tend to
confuse a reader.
∴
```